# bootstrap alert right margin issue?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap alerts in my MVC application. When alert appears, it take left margin but on right side it take no margin.

I have not done any modification in css, not sure it is correct and default margining.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    It is a test error message. It is test error message.
     It is a test error message. It is test error message.
     It is a test error message. It is test error message.
     It is a test error message. It is test error message.
     It is a test error message. It is test error message.

</div>
```

I tried putting this in a div and adding

**What I tried ?**

I tried putting this code in a div and apply `.input-append` on outer div. As a results alert flicks for a section and hide automatically and remaining on screen is as below:

[image]

**What Help I need ?**

Can you please guide me how I can make margins equal on left and right side, is there a default class for it in bootstrap ?

**EDIT**
I understand I can centralize this div my `fixing width` and setting `margins:auto` but concern is fixing width will it remain respnsive as it is basic purpose of using bootstrap ? I m not sure in modifying what styles I should modify and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Center the whole div which would automatically provide the right margins:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error" style="width:800px margin: 0 auto;">
```

if the width of the white outer box is 1000px, then you would have 100px margin on every side

Comment: thanks, fixing width and setting margin, will it remain responsive ? What my concern is purpose of using bootstrap is, it is responsive. I m not sure what sort of css modification I should do ?

Comment: You could experiment with setting the width to a percentage, then set the margin

Answer (score 1):

The proper code is:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    It is a test error message. It is test error message.
    It is a test error message. It is test error message.
    It is a test error message. It is test error message.
    It is a test error message. It is test error message.
    It is a test error message. It is test error message.

</div>
```

The margins/paddings are applied to the parent divs, not the alert div itself

http://jsfiddle.net/N5aG5/1/

Answer (score 0):

since You are using Bootstrap, You could use their grid system to keep Your design responsive, for example:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-error col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    It is a test error message. It is test error message.
    ...
</div>
```

I also add class *text-center* to make it look better in case of short texts.